# Tag Synonyms / Merging: Estimates

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-merge

Right now, we have 4 estimation tags on SESE: [estimation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/estimation) and its unmerged synonym [time-estimation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-estimation) (239 questions), [cost-estimation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cost-estimation) (29 questions), and [workload-estimation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/workload-estimation) (11 questions).

I present two questions to the community:

Should the cost-estimation and workload-estimation tags have a target synonym of estimation? Should these tags be merged?

I believe the answer to both is yes - the process of all different kinds of estimation is close enough that someone skilled in one can most likely help with the others, and it doesn't make sense to split questions about estimation across many tags. But before I go do this, I want to hear from the community.

Comment: Go for it. I don't believe that tag searching is a good mechanism for nuances. And a new user would likely be confused by the multiple options offered currently.